# Create an order from several incomplete orders

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, computer-science, graph-theory

Here is the motivation and how it should behave, but I need a help how to implement it.

I have several (typically) incomplete orders given as ordered values, for ex.:
1. A, C, D
2. D, E
3. X, B
4. B, C
5. C, F
6. C, A

and the resulting order should be:
A, X, B, C, D, E, F or A, X, B, C, F, D, E or A, X, B, C, D, F, E

The idea behind it is sort the result based on first seen order. I will try explain it on the example in steps:
order A, C, D
D, E - D seen, so add E after D, so order A, C, D, E
X, B - no value seen yet, so we can not determine the order now, so create 2nd temporary order X, B
B, C - C already seen, so order A, B, C, D, E
and 2nd order can be merged via B, so A, X, B, C, D, E
C, F - C see, so order A, X, B, C, D, E, F
C, A - ignore, both values are part of already defined order (by first incomplete order A, C, D)

But what if an additional incomplete order F, D or F, E will be part (added to the end) of the input? The step-by-step mental algorithm will fail - F was already placed.

How can the idea be implemented, any idea?

Comment: Do you have a more formal definition of the expected result? Particularly it is not clear how you deal with contradictions between different partial orders (`A - C` in your example between #1 and #6). Can there really be contradictions? If so, does the earlier sequence always win? Or can an algorithm choose the winner arbitrary? Is there any other logic? What  happens if the contradiction is produced a longer cycle? Does the last sequence always lose? Example: #1 `A, B, C` #2 `B, C, D` #3 `C, D, A`. What is the expected result?

Comment: Does the order of values in the incomplete orders have to use the same ordering as in the resulting order?

Comment: The solution to this problem is [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort).